# Does using Express ACH for fee makes sense?

Tags: united-states, ach

[nacha.org](https://www.nacha.org/rules/same-day-ach-moving-payments-faster-phase-3) has started same day ACH. There are some banks and other [institutions](https://novo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/6177445984660-What-is-Express-ACH-) are starting to use it. On some banks I have seen a message as shown below

> Express Transfer: Your transaction qualifies for faster processing
> than is standard, your external bank may charge a fee

Has any one used Express ACH and does the fee equals 1.5% or it could be less at other institutions ? Does this hefty fee makes sense ?

Comment: If you need to send money faster than regular ACH, but not as quickly as wiring money, then (as long as overnight ACH is cheaper than wiring) *obviously* overnight ACH makes sense.  Of course it makes more sense to not wait until the last minute.

Comment: "Does this make sense", especially when you don't provide context, is likely to be closed as opinion-based. Can you find a way to rephrase so it has a clearer answer than "well, sure, sometimes, maybe"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding this correctly:

Depends on how critical it is for you to get a transfer completed before a specific date. Last-minute payment before being fined, for example. Nice to have available as an option, not something you would use often (one hopes).

Consider it the banking equivalent of an overnight express package service. At least it's cheap compared to those.

Comment: Tgis is the obvious answer.  You pay more for last minute service. just like you pay for wiring money.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some banks may charge a fee for express ACH. However, the amount of the fee will vary depending on the institution. Some banks may charge a flat fee or a percentage fee. It is best to contact the bank or institution to find out the exact fee they charge for express ACH.

It is important to consider if the fee is worth it when deciding whether or not to use express ACH. Fees can add up quickly and may not be worth the convenience of faster processing. It is important to weigh the cost vs the benefit before making a decision.